gfxstream_backend.dll was not found
i am trying to debug an an Android Maui App in Visual Studio 2022 (v17.11) using the Windows Subsystem for Android (Android 13.0 -API 33).
But i get this error:
The code execution cannot proceed because gfxstream_backend.dll was not found. reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
I tried repairing Visual Studio but that did not help. I updated the Android Device Manager. I uninstalled the Android Emulator in the Android SDK and then reinstalled it.
None of these steps have helped.
What should i do now?

Try to restart adb server from command line:

adb connect 127.0.0.1:58526

You can get the actual IP an port from Android Subsystem window > Advanced parameters.
